Unable to connect C# application to Azure SQL
I know this question has been asked many times before but I have been through all the threads and I am still having issues.
I am trying to connect a c# application to insert data to an azure SQL database.
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "claimsportaldbserver.database.windows.net";
        builder.UserID = "username@domain.com@claimsportaldbserver";
        builder.Password = "password";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "Claims Portal_db";

        try
        {
            using (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {

                String sql = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Claims]";

                using (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

Below is a list of things I have tried which were from various forms and documentation

I copied the connection string details from azure so there are no spelling mistakes.
Added my IP address to the azure firewall rules.
Added port 1433 to my own firewall rules.
Use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and not System.Data.SqlClient.
Added ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol to the code.
Added WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials to the code.

However, I am still getting the message "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)"
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you


try to connect with SSMS to rule out connectivity issues.

Hi @DerekGusoff
Thanks for the quick response. When I try to connect to SSMS from my development pc, which I remote on to, I get the same error as I do when I try to debug the code. When I deploy the code to the server I also get the same error. However, I can connect via SSMS from my laptop. I do not have Visual Studio on my laptop to test the code.
I have also ran a telent command from my development PC which returned “Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed”.
Other than the firewall rules is there anything else that could be stopping the connection?

then your code is not the problem, so you can forget all that. If you're remoting into a dev machine, and running code from there, the dev machine needs connectivity. Is the dev machine connected to the internet? Does the dev machine have a firewall rule?

Yes it has internet and I created an Outbound firewall rule which I attached a screenshot in the post.

does the Azure firewall on the Sql server have your dev machine outbound ip address?

Yep, just want to confirm I did this right though. I pinged my development PC and copied the IP address, then set this as a firewall rule on the Azure SQL Server with the IP address as the Start IP4 address and the End IP4 address.

That is probably not the outbound ip address.  If you open the Azure portal on your dev machine it should show you the outbound value for the machine on the Network tab.

This post has other ways to find it https://superuser.com/questions/215855/how-can-i-find-out-my-hosting-servers-outbound-ip-address

I went on to do what you suggested but the IPv4 IP that I previously copied and set as a rule was the same IP that the Azure portal was detecting.

Could there be an antivirus or anything that could be stopping the connection? I suspect this is something Ill need to raise with my ICT department

Yes something is blocking your connection, until you can resolve being able to connect with SSMS you are stuck.

Make sure your server name is correct without any spaces and credentials are correct.


In my case, the server name had a space between "dbservere" and ".database.windows.net." Even though the server name was correct, the space prevented me from connecting to the SQL server. To resolve the issue, I went to the Azure portal and copied the name from the portal itself, as mentioned below:

After trying to connect using the above server name and credentials, it connected successfully without any errors, as shown below:

Along with that, check the following options while connecting to the SQL server:

Make sure outbound traffic over port 1433 is allowed by your network's firewall.
Make sure you have provided the correct details of the SQL server.
If all are correct then try to connect with your network team regarding it.

If you are able to connect through SSMS, then you will be able to connect to application successfully. For more information, you can refer to this  MS DOC.
